# Pycharm изменить цвет выбранного элемента в project inspector

Tags: python, linux, pycharm

Как изменить цвет выбранного python файла? Нашел только как менять цветовую схему редактор, а project inspector нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вопросы к разработичкам адресуйте, пожалуйста, самим разработчикам.

Comment: Перенес дополнение из вопроса в ответ. Чтобы вам было удобно отвечать на комментарии, рекомендую зарегистрироваться на сайте.